# Device Driver Compilation

Tags: linux-kernel

I am having some problems regarding compiling device drivers for linux
when i compile i am getting the following error

No rule to make target `/root/aarif/mydev.c', needed by`/root/aarif/mydev.o'.  Stop

the Makefile used is

```
obj-m=mydev.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

test:test.c
        cc -o test test.c
```

thanks

Comment: Where's the rule to compile a C file to an object file?!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what exactly do you think is missing?  The only reference to an object file I see is in the obj-m variable which will be handled by the makefile in the kernel sources which this makefile invokes in order to have it's out-of-tree module built.

Answer (score 0):

Well do you have a mydev.c file?

Alternatively, try adding `mydev-objs := test.o`, assuming your source file is test.c

Comment: Yes, looks like either mydev.c is in a different directory from the one in which make was invoked, or else that is not actually the name of the source file.